# UITableView cell on double click should go to previous state

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

If I select (click) row of TableView, it should add Image saying that I selected this particular Item. It's working fine!

My problem is: if user want to move back from that selected item.
If I click on the same row it should deselect that cell and hide that image.

What I tried is:

```
func tableView (_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return tableData.count
        }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! leistungCell

    // Configure the cell...
    let tableData = self.tableData[indexPath.row]

    cell.leistungLbl.text = tableData["leistung_info"] as? String

    //space between Rows
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = colorLightGray
    cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor


    //space between Rows
    cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
    cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 8

    return cell


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)


    cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "check.png")

    let value = Info["leistung_info"] as! String     

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell?.imageView?.image = nil
}
```

Comment: what issue faced ?

Comment: @KKRocks when I click the same cell again , which I had previously selected the image will not go It will be still visible. I want that image to be hide from that cell.

Comment: you need to reload cell after  cell?.imageView?.image = nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget and remove `didDeSelectRowAt`, just use `didSelectRowAt`, and an array to save selections:

```
var selectedIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    if let index = selectedIndexPaths.index(of: indexPath) { //deselect it if the row is selected
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        cell?.imageView?.image = nil
        selectedIndexPaths.remove(at: index)
    }
    else{ //select it if the row is deselected
        cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "check.png")
        selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
    }
}
```

And be aware of that the cells are being **REUSED** ! Please do the same check in `cellForRowAt` method.

Comment: Glad to help! The Pablo's edit improved the selection status. Thanks to him.

Comment: @Spurti, and be aware of that the cells are being REUSED ! Please do the same check in cellForRowAt method.

Comment: ChHEN ya I will do it. Thanks :-)

Comment: I have one more question : I have 5 buttons when user clicks each will popup subview xyz with table . But I don't want to show the selected items what previous Button had selected , I want to upload fresh table or subview.

Comment: @IBAction func click_leistung(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        leistungTableView.isHidden = false
    
            let x_View = 400
            let y_View = 120
            let width_View = 400
            let height_View = 1000
            
    
           leistungTableView.bounds = CGRect(x: x_View , y: y_View, width: width_View, height: height_View)
            view.addSubview(leistungTableView)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            
            }

Comment: It's hard to understand your new question, could you please post a new question with more details, and leave a link here?