# didDeselectRowAtIndexPath is not called when the checkbox is checked aleady

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, checkbox

Im using UITableView with checkboxes. In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I have  set selected few cells as follows,

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


if(tableView == self.sideBarTbl){
    cell.textLabel.text = [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.tag = indexPath.row;
    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        [cell setSelected:true];
    }else if(indexPath.row == 1){
        [cell setSelected:true];
    }else {
        [cell setSelected:false];
    }
}
```

In short, if the row is 0,1 then Im checking the checkboxes of the UITableView.

when the user clicks the row 0 or row 1, it should call `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` since row 0 and row 1 checkmarks are already checked. But, it is always calling the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. no matter if the checkbox is checked or not, it always calls the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. How can I let it call `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` when the checkbox is checked and call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` when the checkbox is not checked?

Comment: add cellForRowAtIndexPath method .

Comment: you can use mutablearray for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` instead of `[cell setSelected:true];`

```
  [tableView  selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];`
```

Use the following code when the  user wants to deselect. Use it in your `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`

`[tableView  deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];`

Finally, you can get the selected indexes as follows,

```
-(void) getSelectedIndices
{
    NSArray *indexPathArray = [tableView  indexPathsForSelectedRows];
    for(NSIndexPath *index in indexPathArray)
    {
        NSLog(@"Index: %ld",(long)index.row);
    }
}
```

Revert back in case if you have any queries

Answer (score 1):

`didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` method will only be called for cells which has been touched to select before. It's not related to the cell's `selected` property. If you want to do something for deselected cells, just record the selection manually in NSMutableArray with `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. Forget the `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`. For reference: [UITableView cell on double click should go to previous state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44281577/uitableview-cell-on-double-click-should-go-to-previous-state/44281778#44281778)

And an Objective-C example:

```
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate> {
    NSMutableArray *selectedIndexPaths;
}

@implementation SomeViewController
//......
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    selectedIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [selectedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
        //Do something when deselecting.
    }
    else{
        [selectedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
        //Do something when selecting.
    }
}
//......
@end
```

If the selection is single and exclusive, like a radiobox, just use single variable `NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;` to record selection in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, after handling the deselecting process for previous selected cell.